Funcionamiento de static en Java
No termino de entender el funcionamiento de static en este caso:
Supongamos que Panda es una clase y que tiene la variable static count
Panda p = new Panda();
System.out.print(p.count); //0
p = null;
System.out.print(p.count); //O **

Al ser static es facil de entender que podemos acceder a la variable count mediante la clase Panda.count; ya que no depende de ninguna instancia.
Pero una vez p=null; la referencia p ya no apunta a ningún objeto de Panda. Entonces, ¿por que podemos acceder al la variable static a través del objeto (instancia de Panda) aunque no no estemos apuntado a ella?
No debería dar un NullPointerException?

La razón para no lanzar un NPE es porque, cuando accedes a una propiedad de una clase, se espera que uses el nombre de la clase:
Panda.count = 9;

El hecho de que el compilador te permita acceder a través de una variable declarada con dicha clase es "azúcar sintáctico" que realmente no deberías usar porque lleva a este tipo de malentendidos: al compilar el código se sustituye la variable por la clase, por lo que
p.count

Se reemplaza de manera transparente por
Panda.count


Me ha gustado tu respuesta. Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Revisemos el siguiente código:
public class Panda {

   public static int point = 0;
   public int punto = 0;

   public Panda() {
      point ++;
      punto ++;
   }

   public int getPunto() {
      return punto;
   }
}

public class x {

   public static void main( String arr[] ) {

        // esta línea imprime "0", y nos muestra que no es necesario crear un objeto
        // para que exista el campo "point", que no es un atributo de la clase
      System.out.println( Panda.point );
      Panda panda[] = new Panda[ 5 ];
      for( int i = 0; i < panda.length; i ++ ) {
         panda[ i ] = new Panda();

           // acá las distintas iteraciones, irán imprimiendo sucesivamente 
           // "point = 0", "point = 1", "point = 2", lo que nos muestra otra característica 
           // de los miembros estáticos, el valor es el mismo para todos los objetos 
           // (porque son independientes de ellos), en cambio, siempre se imprimirá
           // "punto = 1", ya que cada objeto tendrá su propio valor de "punto"
         System.out.println( "point = " + panda[ i ].point );
         System.out.println( "punto = " + panda[ i ].getPunto() );
      }

        // finalmente imprimimos el valor actual de "point"
      System.out.println( Panda.point );
   }
}

En resumen, un campo estático,
1 - no forma parte de ningún objeto,
2 - se puede acceder a el, invocandolo con el nombre de la clase, o con sus "getters y setters",
3 - el valor del mismo, es compartido por todos los objetos.
Espero que este tonto ejemplo te haya aclarado un poco el tema.
